# Pulling information to unbound fields

Tags: mysql, sql, database, vba, ms-access

I am trying to pull data from an unlinked table to a form with unbound fields. I already have a form where you enter the data and send it to the table but this is to be able to pull it back and update.

This is what I have

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT * " & _
" FROM [" & Address & "].[BusinessAccountOpening]" & _
" WHERE [ID]= " & Me![txtID] & ""

Forms!frm_ViewUpdateRecords!Sub_Details.Form.subaddthedata
```

But getting the error. An RunSQL action requires an argument consisting of an sql statement.

Please help

Comment: Why do you have the two double quotes after the `SELECT`? I suggest you PRINT your statement (`DoCmd.RunSQL`) and post it.

Comment: By the way, if you edit your code and make your SQL statement more readable, you will gain clarity (and more people willing to examine it).

Comment: Thanks, I have tried something different could you have a look

Comment: To the best of my recollection, MySQL does not use `[]` to delimit names but back tilde `\``. And again, make a printout of the query you are sending.

Answer (score 0):

*DoCmd.RunSQL* and *CurrentDb.Execute* are for action queries (delete, update, append) while you present a select query.

So call DoCmd.OpenQuery ... or assign the records to a recordset.

Comment: putting Docmd.OpenQuery I get the error that it cannot find the object

Comment: Well, yes. An _SQL string_ can be a query but not a _QueryDef_ object. So assign your SQL to a QueryDef object.